# Iis there a way to set the font color in the title field for a specific user story or defect in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I would like to be able to customize the font color and size in a specific user story in TFS.

I have added a user story to the backlog in TFS the title is;

> < --^--^--^--^--Needs Triage --^--^--^--^-- >

I have done this to easily call out the defects and stories that have been added to the back log since the last time we had a triage.

I think it would increase the usability if I could make this title pop out in the list view and am hoping there is a way to easily set the color.

Comment: I don't see an option to specify the title header with specific font or color. One of the option would be to have such items under different Areas/Iterations if it works for you. Otherwise stick with your option.

Comment: @catbadger Stack Overflow is for questions about programming and **tools commonly used by developers**. There are literally thousands of questions about TFS on this site.

Comment: I'd suggest to use tags in TFS/VSTS to easily match these items. But you can also query on the created/modified since field to quickly find all new and modified items since your last triage.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use the Styling Rules on your Board view

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/customize-cards